# gnome-control-center crash when clicking on Wifi 'gear' (network settings)

Tags: networking, gnome, 19.04, crash, gnome-control-center

Currently running Ubuntu 19.04, Gnome 3.32.2.

When I try to connect or select a previous Wifi connection that need username/password (no redirecting page/login page) gnome-control-center simply crash and does nothing else. 
Running from cli gives this error:

```
(gnome-control-center:26920): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 10:07:23.753: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nm-applet.eap' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped in my case:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome
```